# updating .bashrc using chef recipes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

i am writing practice recipe for installing jsk using chef-solo, i need to update .bashrc file to set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables. i don't know how to do it. can anyone tell me how to do it.
some of my code is..

```
file "/home/user/.bashrc" do
    owner   "root"
    #something goes here.... i don't know what. but i write
    #%{bash -i -c "source /etc/bash/bashrc && bashrc update"}

    content "JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.1.0.05"
    content "PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin"

  end
```

i do not understand what does `command`%{bash -i -c "source /etc/bash/bashrc && bashrc update"}mean. thanks

Comment: There is a correct answer to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15028179/1437361

Answer (score 5):

First off, `/etc/skel/` is the directory that's copied when a new user is created. Changing the bashrc there will not affect your already existing users, so you maybe you want to change a different file?

Second, the commented out command starts a new bash shell, and in that shell sources `/etc/bash/bashrc` (to reload it), and then does `bashrc update`. I have no idea what that does, it's probably a shell script on your machine?
And why do you want to call that? It doesn't even reference the file you change.

Thirdly, you call `content` twice, which means only the second line will be in that file.

What you probably want to do is:

Create a file `files/default/bashrc` and copy your entire bashrc (including the Java lines) into there.
Replace your code above with:

```
file "/home/whateveruseryouwant/.bashrc" do
  owner "whateveruseryouwant"
  group "whateveruseryouwant"
  source "bashrc"
end
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your time. but here all i want is to update the .bashrc file and set java_home and path variables as i am writing my first recipe for installing jdk on linux using chef solo. How to do that. thanks.