# updating file using 'file' chef-solo resource

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

i am trying to install java using `chef-solo`. The problem is to set the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables in `/etc/profile` file. I tried using `'file'` resource provided by chef. here is some of my code:

```
java_home = "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_05"
path = "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin"

execute "make_dir" do
  cwd "/usr/lib/"
  user "root"
  command "mkdir java"
end

execute "copy" do
  cwd "/usr/lib/java"
  user "root"
  command "cp -r /home/user/Downloads/jdk1* /usr/lib/java"
end

file "/etc/profile" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  action :touch
  content JAVA_HOME
  content PATH
end
```

but the problem is `content` command overrides all the content of file, is there any way to UPDATE the file while using chef-solo resources. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** i have found some code from `chef-recipe`, but i am not sure what it does exactly, the code  is..

```
ruby_block  "set-env-java-home" do
  block do
    ENV["JAVA_HOME"] = java_home
  end
end
```

Does it set JAVA_HOME variable for only that  instance or permanently? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 14):

Use [Chef::Util::FileEdit](http://rubydoc.info/gems/chef/11.2.0/Chef/Util/FileEdit). Below is an example how I modify `.bashrc`. The idea here is that I just add:

```
# Include user specific settings
if [ -f ~/.bashrc_user ]; then . ~/.bashrc_user; fi
```

to the end of default `.bashrc`and all other modifications take place in `.bashrc_user` that is part of my cookbook.

```
cookbook_file "#{ENV['HOME']}/.bashrc_user" do
  user "user"
  group "user"
  mode 00644
end

ruby_block "include-bashrc-user" do
  block do
    file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("#{ENV['HOME']}/.bashrc")
    file.insert_line_if_no_match(
      "# Include user specific settings",
      "\n# Include user specific settings\nif [ -f ~/.bashrc_user ]; then . ~/.bashrc_user; fi"
    )
    file.write_file
  end
end
```

Comment: I prefer using [line cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/line) for a more refined way to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

As @user272735 's suggestion, a clean way to modify `.bashrc` is:

1. write all your modification in a `.bashrc_local` file,
2. include your specific settings to `.bashrc`.

For step 1, we can use [template resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html). 
For step 2, I prefer use [line cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/line).

Sample codes as below,

`templates/bashrc_local.erb`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_05
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin
```

`recipes/default.rb`

```
# add bashrc_local
template "#{ENV['HOME']}/.bashrc_local" do
  source 'bashrc_local.erb'
  mode 00644
end

# update bashrc
append_if_no_line "add bashrc_local" do
  path "#{ENV['HOME']}/.bashrc"
  line "if [ -f ~/.bashrc_local ]; then . ~/.bashrc_local; fi"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by either using a template resource instead of a file resource, or if you are just appending those two variables, try doing this:

```
content "#{java_home}\n#{path}"
```

The second content line is overriding the first, as you have already discovered. You also don't need the `action :touch`.

Comment: exactly, content " " command overrides the content already exist. i just want to append two lines(the envt variables). content command does not help.